# PHP isolate data by values of another Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a mutlidimensional array, with values that are the times that keys are duplicated.

This is a part of my array.

```
{
    ["STANDARD:sNN0.20"]=> int(4),
    ["INFO_COMP_1:sNN0.32"]=> int(1), 
    ["INFO_COMP_2:sNN0.32"]=> int(4),
    ["COMM_TYPE:nNN0.1"]=> int(3),
    ["CRC16_D747_MONNAIE:nNN0.4"]=> int(4),
    ["CRC16_D782_CLEFEMV:nNN0.4"]=> int(1), 
    ["CRC16_D787_AIDEMV:nNN0.4"]=> int(2)
}
```

So what I want to do is, create another array where values are equals to 4.

The result would return something like that :

```
["STANDARD:sNN0.20", "INFO_COMP_2:sNN0.32", "CRC16_D747_MONNAIE:nNN0.4"]
```

Comment: That isn't a valid array

Comment: `array_filter($arr, function ($i) { return $i == 4 })`…?

Comment: Create a function that receives the array, iterate with foreach and append the keys into a new array where the values are the ones that you want to filter. Return the new array.

Comment: The headline is by the way confusing.

Comment: @JimWright I know, it is the response that I was too lazy to rewrite correctly.

Comment: _"I know, it is the response that I was too lazy to rewrite correctly"_ - Don't be lazy when you ask people for help. It's very important that you write your question properly to avoid misunderstandings and that people focuses on the wrong issues. If you can't bother writing the question properly, why would you expect us to bother answering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question after trying again :

```
$arr = [];

//$array_count_values is my initial array.
foreach ($array_count_values as $key => $value){
    if($value == 4){
        array_push($arr, $key);
    }
}

var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: For future reference, if you found the answer by trying your self 17 minutes after you posted the question, you didn't try enough before. Posting here should be your last option, when you're absolutely stuck.

Comment: You are right.. Thanks for reminding me, I'll try harder next time !